# Problems with memory managment in C

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, free, stack-memory

I have the following C function, which is causing me a lot of problems with memory, if I dont free the memory it works fine but when I  call another function i get a malloc memory corrupted error, but I free it I get free invalid pointer. And finally when i define new pointers for fecha and fechaVariable due to the fact that strtok works weird i get corrupted_size vd prev_size error. Can someone help me. Here is my code:

```
void mensual_precipitacion(struct fila *arregloArchivo, char *precipitacion, int estacion){
    float acumulado = 0.00;
    char *fecha;
    char *fechaVariable;

    int i;
    int boolIncorrecto = 1;
    char *mes;
    char *anio;
    char *lluvia;   
    int boolfecha = 1;

    fecha = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    fechaVariable = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    lluvia = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));



    for(i=0;i<cantDatos;i++){

        if(arregloArchivo[i].numero != estacion){
            continue;
        }
        boolIncorrecto =0; 
        if(boolfecha){
            strcpy(fecha,arregloArchivo[i].fecha);  
            boolfecha = 0;

            fecha = strtok(fecha,"/");

            mes = strtok(NULL,"/");
            anio = strtok(NULL," ");
        }

        strcpy(fechaVariable,arregloArchivo[i].fecha);

        fechaVariable = strtok(fechaVariable,"/");

        fechaVariable = strtok(NULL, "/");

        if(strcmp(mes,fechaVariable) == 0){
            acumulado += arregloArchivo[i].precipitacion;

        }else{

            sprintf(lluvia,"%s/%s:%f[mm]\n",mes,anio,acumulado);
            strcat(precipitacion,lluvia);
            acumulado = 0.00;
            boolfecha = 1;
            memset(lluvia,'\0',sizeof(lluvia));
        }

    }
    if(boolIncorrecto){
        strcpy(lluvia,"Nro de estacion inexistente");
    }else{
        sprintf(lluvia,"%s/%s:%f[mm]\n",mes,anio,acumulado);
    }
    //
        //printf("%s\n",lluvia );
    strcat(precipitacion,lluvia);

    free(fecha);
    free(fechaVariable);    
    free(lluvia);
}
```

Comment: Using the new `strtok_s()` function is preferable to the older `strtok()` since it has a context argument to allow multiple simultaneous tokenization.

Comment: I prefer using `strncpy()` and `strncat()` which each require a maximum number of characters to copy or concatenate rather than the `strcpy()` and `strcat()` functions just in case there is a missing zero terminator in the string that is being copied from. The idea is to prevent buffer overflow problems by copying too much. Then I put a zero terminator in the last `char` array element to make sure there is always a zero string terminator in the new string. So `char xArray[100];` I would use `strcpy (xArray, aszSource, 100 - 1); xArray[100 - 1] = 0;`

Comment: You also have a problem with the `memset(lluvia,'\0',sizeof(lluvia));` because the size of `lluvia` is the size of a `char *` pointer, 4 bytes on a 32 bit machine. You need to instead specify something like `1000 * sizeof(char)`.

Comment: You don't ever need to multiply by `sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only call `free(ptr)` if the value of `ptr` was returned from `malloc()` or `realloc()`. Your code later has:

```
fecha = strtok(fecha, "/");
```

So when you get to the end of the function, `fecha` no longer contains the pointer that it originally contained when you did:

```
fecha = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
```

You should use a different variable in the loop so that you don't lose the original `fecha` pointer.

You have the same problem with:

```
fechaVariable = strtok(fechaVariable,"/");
```

so use a different variable here as well.

Actually, there's no good reason to use dynamic allocation for these variables at all. Just declare:

```
char fecha[1000], fechaVariable[1000], lluvia[1000];
```

Then use different variables with `strtok`, since you can't assign to array variables.

```
char *fecha_slash = strtok(fecha, "/");
char *fechaVariable_slash = strtok(fechaVariable, "/");
```

Comment: same for `fechaVariable = strtok(fechaVariable,"/");` and `fechaVariable = strtok(NULL, "/");` as well.

Comment: @RichardChambers I created for example *ptr_Fecha = Fecha then I free ptr_Fecha, but when I do this i get the corrupted size vs prev_size error.

Comment: @NicoPassaglia That sounds like you may be writing outside array bounds.

Comment: @Barmar strtok wont let me define the variables as fecha[1000], it says error assignment to expression with array type. Maybe I am writing out of bounds